# MapStruct utilize Mappings from a method into another method having return type of an inherent class

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have started using MapStruct recently and had this doubt. So is it possible to inherit mappings from one method into another method which is being used for mapping a subclass of the previous method's output.

For eg - If I have a class Car which needs to be mapped into two classes FourWheeler and DetailedFourWheeler(which extends the FourWheeler class) can I use the Mappings defined for the conversion of Car to FourWheeler into my method which converts Car to DetailedFourWheeler?
Here is the example code -

```java
@lombok.Data
public class Car {
    private String color;
    private String brand;
    private String variant;
}

@lombok.Data
public class FourWheeler {
    private String paint;
    private String company;
}

@lombok.Data
public class DetailedFourWheeler extends FourWheeler {
    private String model;
}
```

My Mapper for this looks like -

```java
@Mapper
interface FourWheelerMapper {

    public static final FourWheelerMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(FourWheelerMapper.class);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "color", target = "paint"),
            @Mapping(source = "brand", target = "company")
    })
    FourWheeler mapToFourWheeler(Car car);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "color", target = "paint"),
            @Mapping(source = "brand", target = "company"),
            @Mapping(source = "variant", target = "model")
    })
    DetailedFourWheeler mapToDetailedFourWheeler(Car car);
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to change the mapToDetailedFourWheeler like -

```java
@InheritMappingsFromParent
@Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "variant", target = "model")
})
DetailedFourWheeler mapToDetailedFourWheeler(Car car);
```

Here my InheritMappingsFromParent should bring in the mappings for color and brand from the previous method.

I was not able to find something relevant to this in the documentation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct has the `@InheritConfiguration` annotation that will do what you are looking for. Have a look at [Mapping configuration inheritance](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_reusing_mapping_configurations) in the documentation for more information.

In any case for you it will not work if `DetailedFourWheeler` does not extend `FourWheeler`, since without that there is no way for MapStruct to know that the types are related.